# How to view contents of a RDD after using map or split (pyspark)?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to view the contents of the return value of a

```
labID = fields.map(lambda x: x.split('ID')(1).trim())
```

When I do:

```
print(labID)
```

What I see is this:

> `PythonRDD[97] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48`

I see examples of this in Scala, but I can't find examples with pyspark. Scala examples:

```
myRDD.collect().foreach(println)  or myRDD.take(n).foreach(println)
```

How would I do this with pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `collect()` or `take()`, you get back a list of elements in the `rdd`. You can then print these values as you would any normal python list.

Since `collect()` is expensive and slow, I recommend you first try taking a sample of your data to make sure it looks correct:

```
labID = fields.map(lambda x: x.split('ID')[1].trim())
labID_sample = labID.take(5)  # returns the first 5 elements in the rdd as a list

print(labID_sample)  # print the list
```

If you're satisfied that your results look correct, you can grab the whole thing:

```
labID_all = labID.collect()  # returns all elements in the rdd as a list
print(labID_all)
```

Be aware that these operations bring the data back into local memory, going through your master node. If you have a lot of data this could be very slow or it may fail. In that case, you should consider writing the rdd to disk using [`saveAsTextFile()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#saveAsTextFile).